# Bisect the inscribed equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

This question was inspired by
[incircle bisectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2876870/122782),
but in this case 
two inscribed equilateral triangles,
oriented along the corresponding angle bisector,
play the role of the two incircles:

[image]

Using the known expression for the length
of bisector 
\begin{align} 
|CC_0|&=\frac{2 ab\cos\tfrac\gamma2}{a+b}
,
\end{align}
it is easy to find the side length of 
the inscribed $\triangle C_0C_1C_2$:

\begin{align} 
|C_0C_1|=|C_1C_2|=|C_0C_2|=
q
&=
\frac{4ab}{(a+b)
\Big(1+\sqrt3\tan\tfrac\gamma2\Big)
\,\sqrt{1+\cot^2\tfrac\gamma2}}
.
\end{align}

Now, consider the bisection of $\triangle ABC$
with two inscribed equilateral triangles

[image]

Let
\begin{align} 
|AC|&=b
,\quad
|BC|=a
,\quad
|AB|=c
,\\
|AD|&=c_1
,\quad
|BD|=c_2=c-c_1
,\\
|CD|&=d
,\quad
|CC_{00}|=d_1
,\quad
|CC_{10}|=d_2
,\\
|C_{00}C_{01}|&=|C_{01}C_{02}|=|C_{00}C_{02}|
=q_1
,\\
|C_{10}C_{11}|&=|C_{11}C_{12}|=|C_{10}C_{12}|
=q_2
,\\
\angle CAB&=\alpha
,\quad
\angle ABC=\beta
,\quad
\angle BCA=\gamma
,\\
\angle DCA&=\gamma_1
,\quad
\angle BCD=\gamma_2=\gamma-\gamma_1
,\\
\angle ADC&=\delta_c
.
\end{align}

For this configuration we have

\begin{align} 
q_1&=
\frac{4bd}{(b+d)(1+\sqrt3\tan\tfrac{\gamma_1}2)\,\sqrt{1+\cot^2\tfrac{\gamma_1}2}}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
q_2&=
\frac{4ad}{(d+a)(1+\sqrt3\tan\tfrac{\gamma_2}2)\,\sqrt{1+\cot^2\tfrac{\gamma_2}2}}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

The question is: solve \eqref{1}-\eqref{2} for $q_1=q_2$.

It is relatively easy to express \eqref{1}-\eqref{2}
in terms of single parameter, say, $c_1$ 
and solve this numerically,
but is there a way to find simpler analytic solution
e.q. in a polynomial form?

Comment: Why do you think that $CC_1=CC_2$?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Yes, by construction $\triangle CC_2C_1$
is isosceles, same is true for $\triangle CC_{02}C_{01}$
and $\triangle CC_{12}C_{11}$ on the other image.